# Syntax error in aggregate argument in datatable compute Function

Tags: c#, datatable

I am facing this error ": Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier." in a line below. I am unable to resolve the problem. Basically i am trying to sum 'qty' column values where '[BATCH NUM]' column value is equal to combobox selected value.

```
sold_quantity = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(QTY,'System.Int64')", "[BATCH NUM] = '"+Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue)+"'"));
```

Comment: it is not duplicate, it is different code although error type is same.

Comment: i am unable to debug the problem thats why i posted it but i forgot that there are people who dont know answer and they use to flag your question etc

Comment: can you tell what is similarity in both problems ?? You posed objection so you should also tell objection.

Comment: Sir i am learner, i am not a expert, I am trying to learn. If i post question it means that i want to learn. But if i get negative remarks from Stackoverflow then it will surely give me a setback in learning process. So sorry if i pasted a similar question.

Comment: Now i tried this code but it giving error "Syntax error: Missing operand after '[BATCH NUM]' operator." 
sold_quantity = 
    Convert.ToInt64(dt.Compute("Sum(Convert([QTY],'System.Int64')", "dRow[BATCH NUM] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue) + "'"));

Comment: Sorry for that i you felt hurt by my any comment. I have been fighting with this error since 5 days that's why i am in worry and uttered a bit rude attitude. All my tries are going vain. Dont know how to resolve.

Comment: Will take a look a bit later and see if I can find a solution for you.

Comment: okay thanks and again sorry

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a direct solution to your problem, but I did find a workaround:

First, add a calculated column:

```
dt.Columns.Add("LONGQTY", typeof(long), "CONVERT(QTY, 'System.Int64')");
```

Second, use the calculated column for your computation:

```
dt.Compute("sum(LONGQTY)", "[BATCH NUM] = '"+Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue)+"'")
```

Sorry I can't be more helpful. Everything I saw suggested what you're doing should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot John for your solution, I found out solution using LINQ. I have posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my above problem using LINQ, actually problem was that i was not properly mentioned datatype of columns.

```
sold_quantity = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("BATCH NUM") == Combo3_val.ToString()).Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32( row.Field<string>("QTY")));
```